# Expected value of hyper geometric distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**Question:**

Say, I have to calculate the expected value of the number of aces from a deck. I pick cards without replacement. Thus, the distribution of the number of the cards is hypergeometric.

Formally,

```
X=#aces 
Let X_j be indicator of j^{th} card being an ace
E(X_j), where j is in {0,1,2,3,4,5}
```

**Answer:**

```
E(X)=E(X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4+X_5)
E(X_1)+E(X_2)+E(X_3)+E(X_4)+E(X_5) by linearity.
```

Now in the next step,

```
E(X)=5E(X_1)
```

I don't get this why is this True even though the trails are **dependent**.

**Reference:**

Link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LX2q356N2rU&index=9&list=PL2SOU6wwxB0uwwH80KTQ6ht66KWxbzTIo 
                                                                          Time: 38:20

Comment: Do you understand that $\mathbb EX_1=\mathbb EX_2$?

Comment: @drhab No, why so? They are dependent events, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, they are dependent. But if two cards are elected and are given  numbers $1,2$ then why would the probability of card1 (to be an ace) differ from the probability of card2 (to be an ace)? Picking $5$ cards one by one (without replacement) is the same as picking $5$ cards together and afterwards giving them a number. They all have equal probability to be an ace.

Comment: @drhab I don't understand, because here there are 5 separate experiments. We are not selecting 5 cards from a deck.

Comment: There is no essential difference.

Comment: Why? When you do 5 experiments in a sequence, each experiment is conditioned on the outcome from the previous one.

Comment: Doing $5$ experiments in a sequence is exactly the same thing as selecting $5$ cards and giving each of them a distinct number. Your numbering is somehow chronological. That's why you can use terms as "previous".

Comment: Make things small and take $2$ balls from a box containing $1$ red ball and $1$ blue ball (and no other balls). If you take the $2$ balls out (one by one) then what is the probability of the first to be red? And of the second?

Comment: @drhab  First is $1/2$. Second would be conditioned on the first, then $1/2*0$+$1/2*1$? But then sampling with replacement and without are the same?

Comment: Both $\frac12$. That's what I mean. Sampling with or without replacement are different.

Comment: @drhab But the answer is the same for both. Intuitively, I find it weird that the expected values of binomial and hypergeometric are the same.

Comment: Differences will be there concerning questions like: what is the probability that the first and the second ball are red? Your intuition can grow if you repeat the process in your thinking several times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that the $5$ cards are drawn, are numbered $1,2,3,4,5$ chronologically, but not looked at. Then the cards are turned around in order to have a look at them, but we begin with card having number $3$. What will be the probability that this cards turns out to be an ace? You could think of it as **third card drawn**, but also as **first card looked at**. Can you find an essential difference? If so then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

We're working with a sum of indicators. Expected values of indicators are the probability that the indicator is $1$.
$$\begin{align}\mathbb{E}[X_1] &= \dfrac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{0}}{\binom{52}{1}} \\
&= \dfrac{4}{52} \\
\mathbb{E}[X_2] &= \mathbb{E}[X_2 \mid X_1 = 0]\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 0)+\mathbb{E}[X_2 \mid X_1 = 1]\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 1) \\
&= \dfrac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{47}{0}}{\binom{51}{1}}\cdot \dfrac{\binom{4}{0}\binom{48}{1}}{\binom{52}{1}} + \dfrac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{48}{0}}{\binom{51}{1}}\cdot \dfrac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{0}}{\binom{52}{1}} \\
&= \dfrac{4}{52} \\
&= \mathbb{E}[X_1] \\
\mathbb{E}[X_3] &= \mathbb{E}[X_3 \mid X_1 = 0, X_2 = 0]\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 0, X_2 = 0) + \mathbb{E}[X_3 \mid X_1 = 1, X_2 = 0]\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 1, X_2 = 0) + \mathbb{E}[X_3 \mid X_1 = 1, X_2 = 1]\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 1, X_2 = 1)\text{...}
\end{align}$$
See calculation details [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(4%20choose%201)*(47%20choose%200)*(4%20choose%200)*(48%20choose%201)%2F((51%20choose%201)%20*(52%20choose%201))%20%2B%20(3%20choose%201)*(48%20choose%200)*(4%20choose%201)*(48%20choose%200)%2F((51%20choose%201)%20*(52%20choose%201))) for $\mathbb{E}[X_2]$. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: Important is that the OP will find a way to understand that $\mathbb EX_1=\mathbb EX_2$ without elaborations like this.

Comment: @drhab I feel you have that well-covered. I'm just here to show the relevant formulas.